# Autofac - handle multiple requests in ASP.Net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, autofac

I am new to Autofac and IoC so now I try to build my firs ASP.NET MVC 3 application with IoC.

Here with this code I try manually to register ProductController (in Global.asax).

```
protected void AutofacIocRegistration()
  {

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    //PRODUCT CONTROLLER
    var registration = builder.Register(c => new ProductsController(c.Resolve<IProductRepository>()));
    builder.RegisterType<ProductsController>().InstancePerHttpRequest();

    SqlProductsRepository productRepository =  new SqlProductsRepository(DATABASE_CONNECTION);
    builder.RegisterInstance(new ProductsController(productRepository));

    IContainer container = builder.Build();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

}
```

When I build the application for the first time, I get list of 4 products in the HTML page (as I expected), but when I refresh the page or go "next" to other list of products then I get the error

> A single instance of controller
>   'WebUI.Controllers.ProductsController'
>   cannot be used to handle multiple
>   requests. If a custom controller
>   factory is in use, make sure that it
>   creates a new instance of the
>   controller for each request.

As you can see in this code

```
builder.RegisterType<ProductsController>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

I try to solve this with InstancePerHttpRequest() method but unsuccessful, if you have any suggestion please post.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below method to register your controllers

```
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

if you are using constructor injection in the controllers you can register your repository like this

```
builder.RegisterType<SqlProductsRepository>().As<IProductRepository>();
```

this way it will create the object graph when it needs to create the controller

Comment: Thanks, now works, in addition I copy the DATABASE_CONNECTION string in the SqlProductsRepository class and remove the parameter from the constructor