# Autofac + MVC3 + Html.Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, autofac

I've got the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281579/autofac-handle-multiple-requests-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

The error message is:
*A single instance of controller 'Search.Web.Controllers.AdvancedController' cannot be used to handle multiple requests. If a custom controller factory is in use, make sure that it creates a new instance of the controller for each request.*

Code in Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

  containerBuilder.RegisterType<AdvancedController>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
  containerBuilder.RegisterType<MemoryBodyTypeRepository>().As<IBodyTypeRepository>;
  containerBuilder.RegisterType<BodyTypePictureClassFinder>().As<IBodyTypePictureClassFinder>();

  var container = containerBuilder.Build();

  DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
  AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

  RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
  RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

This is some Code from AdvancedController:

```
private readonly IBodyTypeRepository _bodyTypeRepository;
private readonly IBodyTypePictureClassFinder _bodyTypePictureClassFinder;

public AdvancedController(IBodyTypeRepository bodyTypeRepository, IBodyTypePictureClassFinder bodyTypePictureClassFinder)
{
    _bodyTypeRepository = bodyTypeRepository;
    _bodyTypePictureClassFinder = bodyTypePictureClassFinder;
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var advancedSearchViewModel = new AdvancedSearchViewModel();        

    return View(advancedSearchViewModel);
}

public ActionResult BodyTypes()
{
    // this uses the repositories to create the ViewModel

    return View(bodyTypesViewModel);
}
```

And the Index View:

```
<div>
    @Html.Action("BodyTypes","Advanced")   
</div>
```

If I execute this View I get the Message stated above. I also tried to remove the InstancePerHttpRequest or use RegisterControllers instead of regestering them explicitly, but that didn't work, too.
If I use RegisterControllers I get the same Error. If I remove InstancePerHttpRequest it somehow executes the whole View two times, which is also not what I'd like to do ;)

I hope anybody can help. This is a real Showstopper for me.

Thansk a lot!!!!

Regards,
Florian Fanderl

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been posted long time ago.
I had same problem, I could solve my problem with your question.
Hope this will be useful for some one in use.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterType<ExtensibleActionInvoker>().As<IActionInvoker>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
            builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).InjectActionInvoker().InstancePerHttpRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<ConfigService>().As<IConfigService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<EntryService>().As<IEntryService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<UserService>().As<IUserService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<MessageService>().As<IMessageService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<CloudService>().As<ICloudService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<Services>().As<IServices>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.RegisterType<AccountController>().InstancePerDependency();


            _containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(builder.Build());

            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new AutofacControllerFactory(ContainerProvider));

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

            HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;
            HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;

            // Quartz.NET scheduler
            ISchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            var scheduler = factory.GetScheduler();
            scheduler.JobFactory = new AutofacJobFactory(ContainerProvider);
            scheduler.Start();
        }
```

if you notice this is my someController

```
builder.RegisterType<AccountController>().InstancePerDependency();
```